# Laravel: How to retrieve a named route, but assign parameters later

Tags: php, laravel, routes, repository-pattern

I like to simplify my controllers as much as possible. When dealing with APIs, I sometimes use a service class (repository?) method that expects some input as well as a `RedirectResponse` like so:

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate([...]);
        return MyService::createWithResponse(
            input: $validated,
            response: back()
        );
    }
}
```

I can focus on **just** I/O here. `MyService::createWithResponse` will handle all the repository logic, but it will also handle error/success messaging:

```php
use \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;

class MyService
{
    public static function createWithResponse(array $input, RedirectResponse $response)
    {
        // ...repository logic dealing with the third-party API
        if (/* the API sends me an error */) {
            return $response->with(['error' => $some_error]);
        }
        $resourceId = /**/;
        return $response->with(['success' => 'Your resource has been created!']);
    }
}
```

Well let's say I have:

```php
Route::get('/resources/{resourceId}', ...)->name('resources.show');
```

and I'm trying to find a way to call `createWithResponse` with a `response()->redirectToRoute('resources.show')`, but I want to pass route parameters (that `$resourceId`) LATER; I don't yet know the `resourceId` until I've run the repository logic.

I can't just pass the route name string into `createWithResponse`, since the expected `RedirectResponse` might not be for a named route, or I may have already added parameters to the `RedirectResponse` before I passed it. (And in any event, `MyService` should be agnostic, and that information should stay in the Controller.)

**How can I pass around a `Route` retrieved by name, then attach parameters later?** Or is there some other way you would do this? I have been looking off and on for weeks for a solution.

Comment: I don't see how you can create a redirect response without knowing the url, you will have to defer the redirect part until you know where to redirect

Comment: The solution I'm currently using is adding conditional logic to the controller (which is not the I/O flow I was hoping for). Like `$result = MyService::create(...); $resourceId = $result['resourceId']; if( $result['error_msg'] ) { ... } else { ... }` :(

Comment: While looking for perfect code you make complicated one ! it obvious that controller responsable for req/resp not the ServiceClass, you wanna clean your code, use FormRequest then let the ServiceClass do its job and lets the controller handle the response as it should be. overthinking => over engineering => hard to test/maintain later

Comment: @PsyLogic yep, I had that epiphany shortly after I wrote this out. I was putting request/response logic in my service class where it doesn't belong. It should absolutely stay in the controller. I've switched to sending callback functions rather than the response instance and documented it in an answer below. (It was less "overthinking" than "not thinking enough" about separation of concerns.) Thanks.

Comment: I see, looks like fetch or axios thing when you have then() catch(), maybe you can go with that where the service return then() and catch()

Comment: @PsyLogic oh yeah, like have it return a custom class with those chainable methods. Yep, I like that. In my actual implementation I actually have custom `ApiRequest` and `ApiResponse` classes that's abstracting a lot of my logic and error handling, so I could throw on fluent `then()` and `catch()` methods real easily. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit: technically found a way to do this, for anyone who might Google this:**

```php
$routeByName = app('router')->getRoutes()->getByName('resources.show');

$routeUrl = app('url')->toRoute(
    route: $routeByName, // `Route` instance
    parameters: ['resourceId' => 1], // mixed
    absolute: false // boolean, absolute or relative path
);
```

---

One possible better way, though, is to pass success/failure callbacks to the service method. The callback closures can accept data from the results as arguments.

Consider:

```php
use \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;

class MyService
{
    public static function create(
        array $input,
        callable $onSuccess,
        callable $onFailure
    )
    {
        // ...repository logic dealing with the third-party API
        if (/* the API sends me an error */) {
            return $onFailure($some_error);
        }
        $resourceId = /**/;
        return $onSuccess($resourceId);
    }
}
```

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate([...]);
        return MyService::create(
            input: $validated,
            onSuccess: fn(string $resourceId) => response()
                ->redirectToRoute('resources.show', $resourceId)
                ->with(['success' => 'Your resource has been created!']),
            onFailure: fn(string $errorMsg) => back()
                ->with(['error' => $errorMsg])
        );
    }
}
```

This keeps the I/O logic fully in the controller. The service method doesn't need to know what type the response is supposed to be, let the controller define that. Now other parts of the app can use that service method and define their own outputs.

---

Additionally, you can use some PHPDoc "generics" (`@template`) syntactic sugar to help out your IDE and make this more obvious:

```php
class MyService
{
    /**
     * @template TSuccess of mixed
     * @template TFailure of mixed
     * @param array $input
     * @param callable(string):TSuccess $onSuccess
     * @param callable(string):TFailure $onFailure
     * @return TFailure|TSuccess
     */
    public static function create(
        array $input,
        callable $onSuccess,
        callable $onFailure
    )
    {
    ...
```